# Remove wp_posts.menu_order from select

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to return blog posts from wordpress usign this args..but the SELECT returns me the select with `ORDERBY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts`. What can I do to remove wp_posts.menu_order?

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $menus,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order'   => 'DESC',

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Problem was  a plugin